# PHP scraping using Python

Tags: php, python, web-scraping

I am kind of new to scraping and have little knowledge of HTML. I am facing trouble scraping data off of

http://lginf.pmoralg.go.tz/lginformation/reports9a.php?FYID=FY%202010/11

It's a php page with every search returning me to basically the same web address. I've tried the below code:

#### #

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/shashankrai/Downloads/chromedriver' 
# change path as needed

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors"])

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
url = 'http://lginf.pmoralg.go.tz/lginformation/reports9a.php?FYID=FY%202010/11'
url1 = 'http://lginf.pmoralg.go.tz/lginformation/report9a.php'

browser.get(url)
```

#

But I get the following error:

> RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

I have referred to some of the questions on this topic before but I haven't really been able to figure this out.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: FYI: PHP will never be shown to a visitor of a website (unless there is something very wrong) What you are scraping is HTML (and optionally CSS, js etc.). PHP is a server side language, generating the HTML.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was since every report goes back to essentially the same webpage, I don't know how to use the URL to scrape through the information. I think what I should be doing is writing code to search for all the given entries and and then scraping individual ones but as you can see, I'm clearly stuck.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working just fine in my machine although it doesn't do anything more than open the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('http://lginf.pmoralg.go.tz/lginformation/reports9a.php?FYID=FY%202010/11')
```

I think your problem is in the chromedriver installation.

I think you're using Mac so download the last version of [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.30/chromedriver_mac64.zip). Extract it and move it to `/usr/bin/`. also chrome should be installed in your mac in order for that to work! That should do the trick. If that didn't work just tell, if it work mark as solve :)

Comment: Thanks, I did find a way to correct for that. But I can't scrape. Guess I'll spend some time learning HTML! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: tell us what you want to scrape so someone could help you. No problem mate.

just remember @shashankrai, post what you did to solve your problem to help others with the same problem, and if its anything like I said then mark my answer.

Comment: I'm just looking to scrape data on the website I mentioned :)